# Redirect post .net parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, post

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sbRenderOnMe = new StringBuilder();

    string strUser = GetUser().UserName;
    string strKey = "xxxxxxxxx";

    // the form and the data
    sbRenderOnMe.AppendFormat(
        "<html><body><form action=\"http://thepagetologin.com/api/blele.php\" method=\"post\" name=\"form1\">"
        + "<input value=\"gg\" id=\"client\" name=\"client\" type=\"hidden\" />"
        + "<input value=\"{0}\" id=\"key\" name=\"key\" type=\"hidden\" />"
        + "<input value=\"{1}\" id=\"user\" name=\"user\" type=\"hidden\" />"
        + "<input value=\"login\" id=\"action\" name=\"action\" type=\"hidden\" />"
        + "<input name=\"redirect\" value=\"true\" type=\"hidden\" />"
        + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Button1\" value=\"open\" id=\"Button1\" />"
        + "</form>", strKey, strUser);

    // the auto submit
    sbRenderOnMe.AppendFormat("<script>document.form1.submit();</script>");
    sbRenderOnMe.AppendFormat("</body></html>");

    Response.Write(sbRenderOnMe.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

This code generates a button and then submits that button and redirects the user to a new page and logs that user in.

Some of the users are having problem with this code and I think it might be that javascript is not enabled or something else.

Can someone help me rewrinting this code in a plain C# code so I don't have to use this javascript methood above?

Comment: What is the exact problem here?

Comment: If I only knew!  It looks like some users don't get logged in with this code and I think that might be some problem with this code but I'm not sure.  Therefore I would like to try putting this code in the code behind and don't let it render like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
Response.Redirect("http://thepagetologin.com/api/blele.php?client=gg&key="+strKey+"....");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not let the parameters show in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be missing something so I have to ask why do you even need to do JavaScript and all that rendering?

- You seem to be rendering *another form* within the (server-side) `<form/>` of the ASP.Net WebForms Page which you can't do (can't nest forms)
- I can see that one possible reason is that you are/want to, `POST` to an external application (Php). If that is your goal, then `POST` to it using [`Button.PostbackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example copy/pasted from MSDN link (modified to add your php target):

```
<asp:button id="Button1"
  text="Post value to another page" 
  postbackurl="http://thepagetologin.com/api/blele.php" 
  runat="Server">
</asp:button>
```

---

**Update:**

> I'm posting information that I don't want the user to be able to see

In that case your current Javascript implementation doesn't (seem to) meet that requirement either if it's sensitive data. Anything you do *client side* can be inspected/viewed (even if it's not "displayed") - it's trivial to see POSTed data **from browser** - no special tools needed, you can use Chrome/FF/IE built in dev tools...

You'll have to do things *server side* so (sensitive) data isn't "accessible" to the client (at all) - though that will change the flow/depends on the PHP app (the target of the POSTed data). Is the PHP side "your" app?

Comment: Thanks for the help.Well your right I can use this methood but I'm posting information that I don't want the user to be able to see.  I could "hide" the textboxes but you can always see them and their values by view-ing the source.  Is there any way of hiding the textboxes and their values?

Comment: No that is part of the problem that page is not my app so I have no control over that.  Just got an php example how to do it and have to admit that I have no knowledge of php.

Comment: @user3327882 It looks like (guessing on my part) that it's an api? If so, they should/may have api instructions(?) If what you're sending is sensitive info, it seems odd (implementation) imho,,,,